# Pitched yeast into head of wort, will this delay/ruin its effect?

Tags: yeast, pitching

I am a first time home-brewer. Followed the instructions to the letter. When I added the cold water I "splashed" it in to aerate it. The wort had a large head at the time of pitching the yeast. Will this delay or ruin the effect of the yeast?

Pierre

Comment: next time, it's best to rehydrate the yeast in a little body-temperature water and leave for 15 mins, then stir and pitch. The mixture will break through any foam you've stirred up in the wort, and you'll get the maximum number of active yeast cells from the packet.

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly an element of personal opinion when it comes to answering this question.

Many people pitch directly on the foam and then either leave it for 15 minutes to start rehydrating before stirring it in or not bother stirring it in at all. Others tend to stir it straight in.

Either way, it is not going to stop the yeast working and the foam normally dies down fairly quickly anyway, at which time the yeast will be in direct contact with the wort.

Comment: If you don't rehydrate the yeast in water, a non-trivial fraction of cells will die upon contact with the wort. I suppose  whether this is acceptable to an individual is a matter of "personal opinion", but that rehydration is appropriate is not.

Comment: There are many, many people who don't rehydrate and achieve excellent results.  I am one of them.  I advise people to try it both ways and decide for themselves.  That's what I did.  To read a complete discussion of the topic, see http://www.homebrewersassociation.org/forum/index.php?topic=16784.msg211248#msg211248 .

Answer (score 0):

Read this [whole chapter](http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter8.html) about fermentation.  Then read that whole book :p

Most likely you'll be fine.  You want there to be lots of oxygen when you pitch, but in the future keep things moving around for a while after pitching so the yeast gets properly mixed in.

Remember, though, that people made beer for a *really* long time without even knowing what yeast was and things worked out okay. RDWAHAHB!

Comment: while people have been making beer for a long time with relative carelessness, I dare say that the quality of the beer is far from what we today would call acceptable.

Comment: agreed, i only mean to say that it's not worth stressing over - the yeast want to survive and unless they're put in really adverse conditions they'll do it.